# aligning bootstrap text boxes using horizontal form

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a long form with several input fields and i was trying to align an horizontal form. 
On first row, there are 3 fields (col-md-4) and on the second row there have two fields (col-md-8 and col-md-4). How do i get the text boxes right aligned?

[image]

```
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LAST_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LAST_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FIRST_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FIRST_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MIDDLE_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MIDDLE_NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ctrl-align-right" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr class="hrcolor" />
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.STREET, "Street", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.STREET, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CITY, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CITY, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.STATE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.STATE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ZIP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ZIP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML? Only of the above part

Comment: updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `text-align: right` style to the "Middle Name" and "City" columns.

Comment: I tried with a class ctrl-align-right with the css as you had mentioned, but didnt help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually in second row which is "Street" and "City".

```
<!-- Your second Row -->
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.STREET, "Street", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.STREET, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CITY, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CITY, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Within col-md-8 the ration col-md-2 and col-md-10 is not equivalent to first row's col-md-4 as column with 8 cells have more area as compare to 4 cells that's why col-md-2 and col-md-10 are not aligned properly. I tried but haven't found solution with existing bootstrap classes along with different layout alignment.

Now following is my take on the problem with small help with one custom CSS class "form-group-inline" which simply makes "form-group" class to become inline.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Form Group</title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">                
        <style>     
            .form-group-inline{
                display: inline;
            }       
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 100px;">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-1">Label</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">                        
                    </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-1">Label</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-1">Label</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">                              
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr class="divider" />

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-1">Label</label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-inline">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-1">Label</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">                              
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this one and let you know if this helps.